# warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char **’

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to print out the value of `argv` at this point in my code, but when I try to compile it, I get
`warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char **`. I'm not sure what this warning means though. Is `%p` not meant to be used for `argv` even though it's a pointer?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%s%p", "argv = ", argv);
}
```

Comment: So cast it — `printf("argv = %p\n", (void *)argv);`?

Comment: It would seem that printf expects an argument of type ‘void *’, but you gave it type ‘char **. How much more explicit do you want the compiler message to be?

Comment: @Jonathan simply doing a type cast without explanation or knowing what happens inside the machine can quickly result in undefined behavior. It would be good to know why the compiler expects an explicit type cast in this situation.

Comment: casting it to (void*) will fix the warning, but the the output might not be what you actually want. `%p` prints a text representation of the memory address, not the data that's at the address. Also it is not 'meant' to be used for argv specifically, but for any pointer.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Do you want to explain?  Conversions to `void *` and back must be idempotent, so I'm not sure what risk you see in converting to `void *`, especially since the standard unequivocally demands that the value passed for `%p` must be a `void *` (no other pointer type acceptable).

Comment: Thank you. I just started learning c and pointers about a week ago. Still trying to wrap my head around pointers--also didn't know that you could cast pointers.

Comment: "trying to print out the value of argv" What kind of output do you expect?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So why don't you cast it?

```
printf("argv = %p\n", (void *)argv);`
```

The `%p` pointer is specified (POSIX [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html); C11 [§7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1)):

> `p` — The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

Since `char **` is not a `void *`, you need to do the explicit conversion.  The compiler isn't allowed by the standard to do the conversion to `void *` for you — the ellipsis notation in the declaration of `printf()` means that default argument promotions occur, but that affects only the `float` type and integer types smaller than `int` (`short`, `char`, etc).

On most machines these days, that's a no-op.  On the (long obsolete) machine where I learned to program in C, there weren't `void *` yet (too old for the standard), but the equivalent was `char *`, and the value of a `char *` address for a given memory location was different from the pointer value for any other type — the casts were not optional.

Note that I'm assuming you intend to print the value of the address.  If you intend to print the contents, then there's more work to be done.

Comment: Yes, I intended to print the contents of argv, but isn't it supposed to contain an address as its contents?

Comment: There are several ways to look at it. The simplest is as a single pointer, and printing that value is legitimate (but you need to cast it to `void *` when printing the value via `printf()`). Another way of looking at it is as a pointer to the zeroth element of an array of pointers, where each pointer in the array points to a string.  This treats or views the 'contents' as an array of strings, and you'd print those values as shown by [mayur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035556/mayur) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52216444/15168).  Both views are valid but they're different.

Comment: It might also be helpful to contrast the use of a `void *` variable; that doesn't need a cast, because at the point of conversion, both types are known. (I'm thinking of `void *addr = argv; printf("%p", addr);`, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Well, not *any* pointer (type).

According to `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, for the `%p` conversion specifier,

> `p`
>
> The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>   manner.

So, the argument must be of type `void *` (or, a `char*`, given they have the same alignment requirements). Any other type of pointers, must be converted through an explicit cast, as there is no default argument promotion for pointers.

Something like

```
printf("%s%p", "argv = ", (void *)argv);
```

should do.

Comment: This doesn't answer why an explicit type cast is needed in this case. In many other contexts any object pointer is implicitly converted to a void pointer. Why not here?

Comment: @RolandIllig As I mentioned, there is no default argument promotion - what other cases you are referring to?

Comment: `void *ptr = argv;` -- no explicit cast necessary

Answer (score 1):

In order to print `argv` and it's address you need to do

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    printf("address of argv = %p\n", (void *)argv);
    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're doing a different operation from what the question does.  You're printing the strings that are pointed to by the `argv` array, but the code in the question appears to be trying to print the address stored in `argv`.